# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) when using for in loop value in array

Tags: swift3

I keep getting this error when trying to use a variable to declare the element I want to read. I have had a look for solutions everywhere but i can't find a fix for my specific circumstance, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
       var segmentStore : [Int] = []

        // Iterate through the array
        // keeping track of the elements

        for element : Int in segmentStore {



            //if the segment store arrays segment (index) is equal to 0 then...
            if segmentStore[element] == 0 // ---ERROR HERE---
            {

                //declare constant variable with random number between 1 and 25
                aGen[0] = Int(arc4random_uniform(25) + 1)

                //variable lChar segment 0 is equal to the following code plus existing contents
                lChar[0] += String(alphabet[alphabet.index(alphabet.startIndex, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance(aGen[0]))])

                //print the value in array
                print("seg 0 \(element)")
            }

            //if the segment store arrays segment (index) is equal to 1 then...
            else if segmentStore[element] == 1
            {

                aGen[1] = Int(arc4random_uniform(9))

                lChar[1] += String(aGen[1])

                //print the value in array
                print("seg 1 \(element)")
            }

            //if the segment store arrays segment (index) is equal to 2 then...
            else if segmentStore[Int(element)] == 2
            {

                //declare constant variable with random number between 1 and 25
                aGen[2] = Int(arc4random_uniform(25) + 1)

                //variable lChar segment 0 is equal to the following code plus existing contents
                lChar[2] += String(alphabet[alphabet.index(alphabet.startIndex, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance(aGen[2]))])

                //print the value in array
                print("seg 2\(element)")
            }

            else
            {
            print("error!!!")
                erCode = 1
                messageBox()
            }

        }
```

[variable declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WXX8.png)

[code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0T00.png)

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: var segmentStore : [Int] = []

Comment: sorry i didn't know it would covert it if you copied it in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the for loop type:

```
var segmentStore : [Int] = [0,1,2]

//Option A

for index in 0...segmentStore.count-1 {
    var element:Int = segmentStore[index];

    if element == 0 {
        print("Zero");
    } else if element == 1 {
        print("One");
    } else if element == 2 {
        print("Two");
    }else {
        print("Other");
    }
}

//Option B
for element: Int in segmentStore {
    if element == 0 {
        print("Zero");
    } else if element == 1 {
        print("One");
    } else if element == 2 {
        print("Two");
    }else {
        print("Other");
    }
}
```